# Edge and Chrome cannot load pages other than login but firefox works

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis

i'm a .net dev. I am using a gigabyte laptop with code G5 KE 52VN263SH for work. The problem here is that when I build the app on IIS, The app still shows the login page -> successful login redirects to the dashboard page but when I click on the menus Edge and Chrome can't load pages   but firefox still work.

I rechecked my desktop settings in the company office with my laptop but there was no difference, I tried resetting the laptop but it still didn't work. If anyone has ever encountered a similar situation, please share with me how to overcome it, thank you.

Comment: The more troubleshooting you need is to go to packets/requests level to understand what happens under the hood (where browser developer tools or Fiddler helps). Things above the surface won't help much at this stage.

Comment: Reinstall ur chrome and edge, its nth to do with ur computer but ur browser.. otherwise, it might be the javascript libs are outdated and chromium is breaking

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, do you get any error messages when pages can't  load in Edge and Chrome?

Comment: @samwu it's login normally, no error code but when i click on menu it stuck and not load anymore. I have same settings on my desktop but it work well, very strange. I have reset the laptop and reinstalled everything but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can check the Event Viewer or use the developer tool F12 to check if there are related error messages.